# Elmahcore max number of logs

Tags: asp.net-core, elmah

Is it possible specify the maximum number of logs in ElmahCore in ConfigureServices? If so, how?

I have the following in ConfigureServices :

```
      services.AddElmah()
```

If it not possible to set via code, how is it done?

Comment: It is impossible, because `ElmahOptions` does not contains the limit of logs count.

Comment: That's what I though. I've updated the q to ask how it's done

Comment: You can edit `ElmahOptions` in [source code](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore/blob/master/ElmahCore.Mvc/BuilderHelper.cs). But I recommentd that you create a middleware to record the number of logs and compare each time an exception is triggered.